# React-Native: Can't output to the console.log()?

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I'm in a weird state where I'm trying to bug track an issue and output to the console log and I'm not even getting that at this point.

The post is asking for more details but there aren't any. I'm just trying to figure out basic bug tracking at this point.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import { Header, Button, CardSection, Spinner } from './components/common/';
import LoginForm from './components/LoginForm';

class App extends Component {
  state = { loggedIn: null };

  componentWillMount() {
    firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
    authDomain: 'xxxxxxxxx.firebaseapp.com',
    databaseURL: 'https://xxxxxxx.firebaseio.com',
    projectId: 'xxxxx',
    storageBucket: 'xxxxx.appspot.com',
    messagingSenderId: 'xxxxxxxxx'
  });

  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user) {
      this.setState({ loggedIn: true });
    } else {
      this.setState({ loggedIn: false });
    }
  });
}

  renderContent() {
    if (this.state.loggedIn) {
      switch (this.state.loggedIn) {
        case true:
           return console.log('true');
           // return (
           // <CardSection>
           // <Button onPress={() => firebase.auth().signOut()}>
           //   Log Out
           // </Button>
           // </CardSection>
           // );
        case false:
           return console.log('false');
           // return <LoginForm />;
        default:
           return console.log('default');
           // return <Spinner size="large" />;
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Header headerText="Authentication" />
        {this.renderContent()}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Do you have remote debugger with the console open? That's the only way you can see log statements in RN. If you want to see these statements while the device is running you can use `console.warn()` instead which will produce a YellowBox

Comment: @TimH, thanks for the tip. Post your suggestion as an answer please and I'll up-vote you. If you hadn't said that, I would never have seen the IF statement error. ;-)

Comment: @MagicMiles You're welcome. I posted my comment as  answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `this.state.loggedIn` is `null` the whole time, therefore your code enters never the switch statements. Accordingly you don't get an output.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out. It's the IF statement that's right after the renderContent call; it's not supposed to be there. Sorry to bother.